# Django admin many to many recursive field widget shows identical objects

Tags: python, django-admin

I have a scheduling app with a backend managed via Django Admin. The Members table for managing people and their role includes two recursive fields that indicate whether a particular person has an employer (ForeignKey) or is associated with one or more customers (ManyToMany).

The problem is that when adding or editing a Member via Django Admin, the employer picklist and customers picklist display "Member object" for each row instead of the desired list of various company names.

Same problem in Python2.7.3 with Django1.7.1 and in Python3.4.3 with Django1.10.3.

```
# models.py
class Member(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    role_choices = (
        ('Attendee', 'Attendee'),
        ('Customer', 'Customer'),
        ('Registrar', 'Registrar'),
          )

    now = timezone.now()

    role = models.CharField(choices=role_choices, max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    employer = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
                     limit_choices_to={'role': "Customer"})
    customers = models.ManyToManyField('self', limit_choices_to= 
        {'role': "Customer"}, related_name="registrar_customers", 
        null=True, blank=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.role == "Customer":
            name = self.company_name
        elif self.role == "Attendee":
            name = "{} - {}{}".format(self.employer.company_name, 
                self.first_name, self.last_name)
        else:
            name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

        return name

# admin.py
class MemberAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member

    # Form override to force company names into picklists
        customers = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MemberAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            cust_choices = ((obj.id, obj.company_name) for obj 
                            in Member.objects.filter(role = 'Customer'))

            self.fields['employer'].choices = cust_choices
            self.fields['customers'].choices = cust_choices

        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'role', 
                    'created_date', 'employer', 'customers', 'company_name']

class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'role', 
            'created_date', 'employer', 'company_name')

    form = MemberAdminForm

admin.site.register(Member, MemberAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/ the following code works properly. With thanks to Darius at Djangoproject for the solution.

```
# models.py

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Member(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    role_choices = (
        ('Attendee', 'Attendee'),
        ('Customer', 'Customer'),
        ('Registrar', 'Registrar'),
          )

    now = timezone.now()

    role = models.CharField(choices=role_choices, max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    employer = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
                     limit_choices_to={'role': "Customer"})
    customers = models.ManyToManyField('self', limit_choices_to= 
        {'role': "Customer"}, related_name="registrar_customers", 
        null=True, blank=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.role == "Customer":
            name = self.company_name
        elif self.role == "Attendee":
            name = "{} - {}{}".format(self.employer.company_name, 
                self.first_name, self.last_name)
        else:
            name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

        return name
```